# Finding Noun Phrases using through stanford parser

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

I want to find multiple noun phrases in a given sentence, using stanford parser. I am using Java.

Example sentence:

> Picture quality is really good.

Now I need to extract "Picture Quality".

Is there any way to traverse the dependency tree to achieve the desired result?
Also, can stanford parser tag sentences in XML format?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find all noun phrases, then that is probably most easily done by working with the phrase structure parse tree, rather than the dependencies representation.  You could either manual iterate through the nodes of a Tree object and seeing if the label().value() is "NP", or you could use a TregexPattern of "@NP" and then iterate through the NPs with a TregexMatcher.

You can get XML format output from the parser by using the command-line flag of

```
-outputFormatOptions xml
```

or in code by constructing a TreePrint object with an options string of "xml".

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @christopher-manning's answer, here some code that you can use:

```
private List<String> getNounPhrases(Tree parse) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    TregexPattern pattern = TregexPattern.compile("@NP");
    TregexMatcher matcher = pattern.matcher(parse);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Tree match = matcher.getMatch();
        List<Tree> leaves = match.getLeaves();
        System.out.println(leaves);
        // Some Guava magic.
        String nounPhrase = Joiner.on(' ').join(Lists.transform(leaves, Functions.toStringFunction()));
        result.add(nounPhrase);
        List<LabeledWord> labeledYield = match.labeledYield();
        System.out.println("labeledYield: " + labeledYield);
    }
    return result;
}
```